# How to add point_count divieded by some value to map

Tags: javascript, mapbox-gl-js

Using Mapbox GL JS I want to add to the map the number of markers in a cluster divied by 10.

I can add the point_count and point_count_abbreviated attributes as following:

```
map.addSource("uploaded-source", {
            type: "geojson",
            data: geoJSONcontent,
            cluster: true,
            clusterMaxZoom: 15, 
            clusterRadius: 50, 
          });

map.addLayer({
            id: "cluster-count",
            type: "symbol",
            source: "uploaded-source",
            filter: ["has", "point_count"],
            layout: {
              "text-field": "{point_count_abbreviated}",
              "text-font": ["DIN Offc Pro Medium", "Arial Unicode MS Bold"],
              "text-size": 12,
            },
          });
```

How do I add point_count_abbreviated divided by some number to the map?

Unfortunately my JS knowledge is not that advanced, I tried things like:

```
 "text-field"://{point_count_abbreviated}/10
              //String(Number("{point_count_abbreviated}")/10),
              //"{point_count_abbreviated}".slice(0, -1),
              //String(Number(['/', ["get", Number("{point_count_abbreviated}")], Number(10)]))
```

Answer (score 0):

You need a [Mapbox GL expression](https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/style-spec/expressions/).

```
"text-field": ["/", ["get", "point_count"], 10]
```

I'm not sure if it needs to be converted to a string. If so:

```
"text-field": ["to-string", ["/", ["get", "point_count"], 10]]
```